# Display the tableview row selected in NSLog

Tags: iphone, sdk, tableview, nslog

How can I display the cell selected from my tableview in NSLog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**  UITableview delegate and log the **indexPath.row**.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"selected tableview row is %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: as of Xcode 5+ 
NSLog(@"selected tableview row is %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show what is being displayed in the cell, e.g. on its textLabel, use this in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"selected cell textLabel = %@",cell.textLabel.text);
```